# How to add Button in UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

```
navigator=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:contacts];

UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Delete"
       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
       target:self
       action:@selector(makeCall)];

//[[self.navigator navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nextButton];
self.navigator.navigationBar.items=[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextButton];
```

I am adding a button to UINavigationController and got following exception please help me

```
2011-01-03 11:46:26.626 Appointment[2243:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot call setItems:animated: directly on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'
2011-01-03 11:46:26.634 Appointment[2243:207] Stack: (
3040
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the items on a navigation bar directly, you need to go through the navigation item, which you get from the view controller your displaying in the navigation controller. So, 
    contacts.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = yourItem;

Comment: I am not getting please explain

Comment: there is a method on UIViewController which you should override called navigationItem.  This is where you configure the items that will appear on the navigationBar, such leftBarButtonItem, rightBarButtonItem, or titleView.

When you call pushViewController on your navController, the navController looks to the navigationItem implementation of your viewController to know what to display on the navBar.

Comment: Put your object (button, text, etc) in a UIBarButtonItem. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672076/how-to-add-inputtextview-and-uibutton-to-navigation-controllers-toolbar-in-ios8/27672255#27672255