# How to add InputTextView and UIButton to Navigation Controller's toolbar in iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Here's what I have so far:

```
toolBar = self.navigationController?.toolbar
textView = InputTextView(frame: CGRectZero)
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 250/255, alpha: 1)
textView.delegate = self
textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(messageFontSize)
textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 205/255, alpha:1).CGColor
textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
//textView.placeholder = "Message"
textView.scrollsToTop = false
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 3, 3)
//textView.inputView = toolBar
//toolBar.addSubview(textView)

sendButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
sendButton.enabled = false
sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 142/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Disabled)
sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
sendButton.addTarget(self, action: "sendAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
//toolBar.addSubview(sendButton)

self.setToolbarItems([textView, sendButton], animated: false)

// Auto Layout allows `sendButton` to change width, e.g., for localization.
textView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
sendButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 7.5))
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sendButton, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: -2))
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: textView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8))
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
toolBar.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sendButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: toolBar, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))

return toolBar
```

Right now, there are no errors but the InputTextView and UIButton do not appear. I've been able to remove errors by commenting out the lines you see above like `toolBar.addSubview(textView)`. The toolbar is empty.

Comment: You can only add `UIBarButtonItem`s to a toolbar with `setToolbarItems`.

Comment: @LyndseyScott is right, but you can wrap any `UIView` into a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: So I need to create 2 UIViews, and add each item to it's own UIView. Then refer to them as `sendButton as UIBarButtonItem` and `textView as UIBarButtonItem`? Edit: Just saw your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your current code.

(1) Both `textView` and `sendButton` have frames of size `CGRectZero`.

(2) You can only add `UIBarButtonItem`s to a `UIToolbar`; so in order to add your `textView` and `sendButton` to your toolbar, you have to add them to `UIBarButtonItem`s using `initWithCustomView`, ex:

```
toolBar = self.navigationController?.toolbar

textView = InputTextView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 30)) //<-- set frame greater than CGRectZero
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 250/255, alpha: 1)
textView.delegate = self
textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(messageFontSize)
textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 205/255, alpha:1).CGColor
textView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
textView.scrollsToTop = false
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 3, 3, 3)

sendButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)  // <-- add frame (or use sendButton.sizeToFit() once the titleLabel has been added)
sendButton.enabled = false
sendButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
sendButton.setTitle("Send", forState: .Normal)
sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 142/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Disabled)
sendButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 6, bottom: 6, right: 6)
sendButton.addTarget(self, action: "sendAction", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

let textViewItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: textView)
let sendButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: sendButton)

self.setToolbarItems([textViewItem, sendButtonItem], animated: false)
```